# What's a binary/script called "android"?

Tags: android, gear-vr

In the build script of Samsung's Gear VR framework there's a line:

```
android update lib-project -p .
```

What's this "android" and where to get it? Obviously this is a bit hard to google :)

Comment: It's not hard to google.  "android command line"  Here's a shortcut:  https://www.google.com/search?q=android+command+line&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Your link is about adb.

Comment: All of the search results are about adb?  That's not what I saw.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't eat my breakfast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool can be found in the SDK. Take a look at this:

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html

Answer (score 1):

You can find the android binary in $ANDROID_HOME/tools, $ANDROID_HOME is the path to the directory of your android sdk, you can either add it to the $PATH environment variable, or you can just `cd` to `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` then invoke `./android` with required arguments

Answer (score 1):

This is the `android` sdk tool.

It ships with android sdk and is  located at `<sdk directory>/tools/`.

It supports library project update commands:

```
> android --help
> - create lib-project  : Creates a new Android library project.
> - update lib-project  : Updates an Android library project (must already have an AndroidManifest.xml).
```